# Were there any Moneyball-like instances in history of cricket?

Tags: cricket, history, statistics

[Moneyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moneyball_(film)) was an instance in Baseball where the Oakland contingent have used statistics and data science for buying-selling as well as team selection.

So, was there any such instance in the history of cricket, where statistics and predictive analytics have been used?

(Answers can contain history of local leagues like the IPL, CPL, etc too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events of *Moneyball* are now 14 years old; the main story focuses around the 2002 season. The world has moved on enormously in those 14 years and *every* sport uses "advanced statistics"/data science/whatever you want to call it to a greater or lesser extent. It's just not news any more - in fact, it would be more news if a professional team *didn't* have some kind of data science department.

For a specific example to show how stats have become ingrained in the cricket world, see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/KP24/status/572664676917645312) from Kevin Pietersen in 2015, referring to why England can't score 400 in a one-day international:

> Cos the best team isn't playing & too interested in stats!

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.espncricinfo.com/county-cricket-2017/content/story/1070189.html) is a good story of how a county team used 'Moneyball' to win a T20 tournament.

Comment: This is a link only answer, so please summarize the content here as outside link have habit of dying.